# Spreadsheet like control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, spreadsheet, web-controls

Do you know any ASP.Net controls like [Spread for ASP.NET](http://www.farpointspread.com) that can render Excel like pages that has built-in formula evaluation?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Spread?

Comment: Not really. I'm evaluating other products and want more options.

Comment: Looks to me like an advertising :)

Answer (score 0):

SpreadSheetGear is one option: http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DevExpress ASP.NET Spreadsheet](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Spreadsheet/). It has automated formula calculation engine.